# How can I make a scaffold scrollable in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, list, scroll, flutter-layout

I've tried a lot to make a list scrollable, but it never worked.
Everytime I wrapped it in a SingleChildScrollView my list just disappeared.
Can someone help pls

Here is my code:

```
    return Scaffold(
      body:
      SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: subjects.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
            return singleSubject(
              subjects[i],
              () => deleteItem(i),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF383838),
        onPressed: newSubject,
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFB94844),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use `SingleChildScrollView` while `ListView` is the only child on `body`.

Do

```dart
 body: ListView.builder(
```

Find more about [widgets/scrolling](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets/scrolling)